# How do I return an empty result set from a procedure using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm interested in returning an empty result set from SQL Server stored procedures in certain events.

The intended behaviour is that a L2SQL `DataContext.SPName().SingleOrDefault()` will result in CLR null value.

I'm presently using the following solution, but I'm unsure whether it would be considered bad practice, a performance hazard (*I could not find one by reading the execution plan*), or if there is simply a better way:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TableName]
WHERE 0 = 1;
```

The execution plan is a constant scan with a trivial cost associated with it.

The reason I am asking this instead of simply not running any SELECTs is because I'm concerned previous SELECT @scalar or SELECT INTO statements could cause unintended result sets to be served back to L2SQL.  Am I worrying over nothing?

Comment: Looks fine to me - but make sure you leave a comment explaining it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to simply retrieve the metadata of a result set w/o any actual row, use [`SET FMTONLY ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx).

Answer (score 66):

If you need column names in the response then proceed with the `select TOP 0 *` from that table, otherwise just use `SELECT TOP 0 NULL`. It should work pretty fast :)

Comment: For ones who searching for something SQLite-compliant: `SELECT 0 LIMIT 0`

Answer (score 31):

That is a reasonable approach. Another alternative is:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * FROM [dbo].[TableName]
```

Comment: Make it shorter with SELECT TOP 0 0 (the second null is what would be given back, but as you do top 0, it does not do anything and no need to access a table.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best solution is top 0 but not using a dummy table. 
This does it for me

select top 0 null as column1, null as column2.

Using e.g. a system table may be fine for performance but looks unclean.

Answer (score 2):

It's an entirely reasonable approach.

To alleviate any worries about performance (whoch you shouldn't have any in the first place - the server's smart enough to avoid table scanning for 1=0), pick a table that's very small and not heavily used - I'm sure your DB schema has one.